# How to create a docker container using a project solution where lib projects are located one level higher than the building context

Tags: docker, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, docker-compose, solution

I have a VS2017 (v5.18.0) solution which contains a .NET Core 2.0 console application "ReferenceGenerator" as the "startup" application. The solution contains also two .Net Core lib 2.0 projects FwCore and LibReferenceGenerator, which are "homegrown" libs. I have added docker support (Linux) and so all files needed to create a docker application are added. I can debug the application in the "docker-compose" mode with "docker for windows in Linux mode". And the application works fine. If I try to build a release version I get an error that a COPY occurs from an illegal path. The docker file looks like this:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ReferenceGenerator/ReferenceGenerator.csproj 
ReferenceGenerator/
COPY ../LibReferenceGenerator/LibReferenceGenerator.csproj ../LibReferenceGenerator/
COPY ../FwCore/FwCore/FwCore.csproj ../FwCore/FwCore/
RUN dotnet restore 
ReferenceGenerator/ReferenceGenerator.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/ReferenceGenerator
RUN dotnet build ReferenceGenerator.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish ReferenceGenerator.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ReferenceGenerator.dll"]
```

The line with beneath content:

```
COPY ../LibReferenceGenerator/LibReferenceGenerator.csproj ../LibReferenceGenerator/
```

Is causing error:

```
Step 6/17 : COPY ../LibReferenceGenerator/LibReferenceGenerator.csproj ../LibReferenceGenerator/
1>Service 'referencegenerator' failed to build: COPY failed: Forbidden path outside the build context: ../LibReferenceGenerator/LibReferenceGenerator.csproj ()
```

I have read that relative paths are not allowed, so be it. But the output of the compiler is already complete in the bin directory of the project ReferenceGenerator. I already tried to remove the two copy lines referencing the libs but then the build complains about the missing lib project files at the dotnet build stage.

Having some "homebuild" lib projects being included in an solution seems to me a very common situation. I am a newbee on docker containers and I have no idea how to fix this, anyone?

Additional info my file structure looks like this:

```
/Production/ReferenceGenerator/ReferenceGenerator.sln
/Production/ReferenceGenerator/ReferenceGenerator/ReferenceGenerator.csproj
/Production/LibReferenceGenerator/LibReferenceGenerator.csproj
/Production/FwCore/FwCore/FwCore.csproj
/Production/ReferenceGenerator/ReferenceGenerator/Dockerfile
```

Please anyone. The people that tried to help me have not succeeded in doing so. I'm completely stuck in development....

Comment: Can you add the structure of your application (folders + docker file) ?

Comment: Can you add it in your question not in comment ? That way you can format the text. Where is the docker file ?

Comment: Have put the relevant files in the question. Cheers.

Comment: Some advance? Same problem here

Answer (score 1):

The answer is, there is no solution...

If you need libraries you must include them by using (private) nuget libraries.
It is not a neat solution because while debugging you do not have the sources of your libraries available but including libs outside the build context is a no go I learned researching the internet...

Also in a micro-service environment sharing code should be minized to avoid teams breaking code of other teams. Sorry for all developers who liked to have a solution for this problem, again beside a workaround using nuget packages there is none!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one level in the copy.

It should be:
COPY ../../LibReferenceGenerator/LibReferenceGenerator.csproj ../LibReferenceGenerator/

Comment: That did not resolve it. The error now shows the new path..
Service 'referencegenerator' failed to build: COPY failed: Forbidden path outside the build context: ../../Lib/LibReferenceGenerator/LibReferenceGenerator.csproj ()

Comment: It should be ../../LibReferenceGenerator/LibReferenceGenerator.csproj not ../../Lib/LibReferenceGenerator/LibReferenceGenerator.csproj

Comment: Service 'referencegenerator' failed to build: COPY failed: Forbidden path outside the build context: ../../LibReferenceGenerator/LibReferenceGenerator.csproj ()

Comment: Sorry now it is exactly matching your suggestion, but still no solution: Step 6/17 : COPY ../../LibReferenceGenerator/LibReferenceGenerator.csproj ../LibReferenceGenerator/
1>Service 'referencegenerator' failed to build: COPY failed: Forbidden path outside the build context: ../../LibReferenceGenerator/LibReferenceGenerator.csproj ()

Comment: Just saw, It's like King Chung Huang said.
Docker can't access to this file. The files which are accessible from the DockerFile start from the folder of the DockerFile and the subfolders.

Comment: So it seems a bug of VS2017 when adding support for docker they don't understand the concepts of building it... It would be very weird to have to place my libs under the ReferenceGenerator folder, that would mess up  my sources. If I could "tell" to use the dockerfile from the /Production path and move it there would solve it probably I understand from the responses. But how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you can't copy files that exist outside of the build context. When you run a command like `docker image build .`, that last argument (`.`) specifies the build context. That context is copied to the Docker engine for building. Files outside of that (e.g., `../LibReferenceGenerator/LibReferenceGenerator.csproj`) simply don't exist.

So, for your example to work, you need to adjust your build context up one level in order to access `LibReferenceGenerator` and `FwCore`. Then, make the source of your `COPY` instructions relative to that one-level up context.

Note that the default location of the Dockerfile is a file named `Dockerfile` at your build context. You'll need to either move your Dockerfile, or specify a custom path using the `-f, --file` option.

[docker image build documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_build/)

Comment: Thanks for responding, but looking at my file (first section) there is nowhere a "docker image build ." section. So I have no clew in what to edit...

Comment: "docker image build ." is the command you launch (in cmd by ex) to build a docker image

Comment: Based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/visual-studio-tools-for-docker, do you have a docker-compose.yml file in your project? It looks like VS is using Docker Compose to drive image builds. If so, you can modify the build context and path to the Dockerfile there.

Comment: I have managed to alter it indeed. It seems like the move is working. But now I'm still wrestling with the copy function. I have not managed to supply the correct copy commands yet. Keep you posted on progress...

Comment: I can move the Dockerfile to different folders by modifiying docker-compose.yml, but as soon as I alter the context one level higher by altering it from "." into "../" then I end up with a strange lock error from visual studio "OSError: Can not read file in context: D:\source\Production\ReferenceGenerator\.vs\ReferenceGenerator\v15\Server\sqlite3\db.lock" 

The path is correct and the the dblock file is present. So messing with the context seems like breaking the sdk scripts for some reason. What a mess... I like the container idea but it seems a pain in the ass to create one (:.

Comment: Why can't I "instruct docker" to only take what's in the bin directory of "ReferenceGenerator" and build the container from that content. This would include the generated dll.s from the lib in the project, making the project work. And why does debugging work but building a release fails?

Comment: It's up to you how you'd like your Docker image to be built. If you have a process that builds the binaries externally, and then you want to just copy in the final result, that's completely possible. Without knowing your debugging and release processes, it's really hard to say why one works and the other fails.

Comment: VS2017 should take care of that for me. If I move the context one higher the build fails with some strange sql lock failure in some py script deep down in VS2017. So I'm still stuck in my developement. I'm looking for an answer so that my problem is solved.